# soft keyboard does not disappear after removing focus from edittext in child fragement in android

Tags: android, android-layout, slidingmenu

I am using Sliding Drawer Fragment class and I have only EditText and some other TextView below this EditText. When i click on EditText then keyboard shows and i write in it, and i press back, When i press back keyboard disappear but still there is WHITE LAYOUT appear on the below portion of screen ( I mean the textview below edit text still does not shows becasue of while screen appear)

```
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:background="#ff3322"  
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
 android:fillViewport="true">

 <RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="9dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-12dp"
    android:background="@+drawable/red_line"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView03"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#FFFF00"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="41dp" >
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout03"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp" >
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout04"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/RelativeLayout03"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/RelativeLayout03"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="72dp"
        android:text="Canada"
        android:textColor="#ED18B7"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView08"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TextView11"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:text="(001) 855 454 9316"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout05"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/RelativeLayout04"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/RelativeLayout04"
    android:layout_below="@+id/RelativeLayout04"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView13"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="72dp"
        android:text="Australia"
        android:textColor="#ED18B7"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TextView13"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:text="(0061) 280 152 643"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000000" />
</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/RelativeLayout05"
    android:layout_below="@+id/RelativeLayout05"
    android:layout_marginLeft="59dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="254dp"
    android:text="_____"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="#ff3322" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout02"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/RelativeLayout05"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/RelativeLayout05"
    android:layout_below="@+id/RelativeLayout05"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp" >
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout07"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/RelativeLayout02"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/RelativeLayout02"
    android:layout_below="@+id/RelativeLayout02"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp" >
</RelativeLayout>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/TextView02"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TextView03"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="ente name" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Comment: can u post a screenshot?

Comment: Please check with different device, May be it is possible by specific device which runs on law memory.

Comment: @Jaydeeppurohit no it is givign same problme for all devices . the same xml if i use in activity class then it does not give problme

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem and i solved it while putting the below code in the MainActivity OF Frame Layout

```
 <activity 
    android:name="com.shane.pir.carhire.MainActivity"            
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >

</activity>
```